# Google Wave extension for Programmers and their Code

Tags: google-gadget, google-wave, collaborative

Sorry if this is well known but Googling for my answer only came up with links about making Google Wave gadgets.

My question is, are there any Google Wave gadgets that allow for better collaborative code editing? I mean, I can set the font to fixed width etc., but are their any gadgets designed for it?

Responses shouldn't include anything about `git` or `svn`. I use those when I want to use those. This is about Google Wave!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://aaron.oirt.rutgers.edu/myapp/root/gadget/codeGadget
-- its a work in progress. Let me know if you want the source code.
I will package it and release it or something like it for the next WHIFF
release.

Comment: Now this is what I'm talking about!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a huge list of robots available for Wave: http://www.chaaps.com/huge-list-of-125-google-wave-robots-add-bots-and-enjoy-wave.html

Maybe there is one in there?

Comment: I did see a few programming bots like syntax checkers and the like.

Comment: @vgm64: is my answer satisfactory then?

Answer (score 1):

Don't know how well it works but found an extension called [CodeBot](http://wave-samples-gallery.appspot.com/about_app?app_id=28023).